# count no of occurences of a substring in a string using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

[image: its giving count as 2 where as pattern occurred thrice in the string]

It is giving count as 2 where as pattern occurred thrice in the string

```
echo "axxxaaxx" |  grep -o  "xx" | wc -l
echo "axxxaaxx" |  grep -o  "xx"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `-P` will enable PCRE which supports [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
echo "axxxaaxx" | grep -P '(?<=x)x'
```

In this case we are using a lookbehind which means that we will match an `x` which have an `x` before it. This makes us able to have overlapping matches:

How the regex is "evaluated":

```
 xxx
^^
|Cursor
Looking for x on this position, since there is nothing this will not match

 xxx
 ^^
 |Cursor
 Looking for x on this position since it's found we got a match

 xxx
  ^^
  |Cursor
  Looking for x on this position since it's found we got a match
```

Comment: Thanks . This is valid for this case but I was trying to achieve this :

Given a string, return the count of the number of times that a substring length 2 appears in the string and also as the last 2 chars of the string, so "hixxxhi" yields 1 (we won't count the end substring).

last2('hixxhi') → 1
last2('xaxxaxaxx') → 1
last2('axxxaaxx') → 2

Answer (score 2):

`grep` doesnt support overlapping matching of regex. It consumes the characters which get matched. In this case you can enable Perl Compatible Regex (PCRE) using `-p` switch and use positive look ahead assertion like this:

```
$ echo "axxxaaxx" | grep -oP "x(?=x)"
x
x
x
$ echo "axxxaaxx" | grep -oP "x(?=x)" | wc -l
3
$
```

`regex(?=regex2)` Positive look ahead assertion finds all `regex1` after which `regex2` follows. While matching chars for `regex2` it does NOT consume the chars hence that's the reason you get 3 matches.

`x(?=x)` Positive look ahead assertion finds all `x` that has `x` after it.

In the string `xxx`, 1st `x` matches because it has `x` after it, 2nd `x` too and 3rd `x` doesn't.

More info and easy examples can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)

Comment: This is the sub part of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37050030/no-of-occurences-of-patterns-in-string/37050288#37050288